# Struggling with SQL subquery selection

Tags: sql

I'm trying to answer a SQL question for revision purposes but can't seem to work out how to get it to work. The tables in question are:

[image: Tables in question]

The question is asking me to write an SQL command to display for each employee who has a total distance from all journeys of more than 100, the employee's name and the total number of litres used by the employee on all journeys (the number of litres for a journey is distanceInKm / kmPerLitre).

So far I've tried several variations of code beginning with:

```
SELECT 
    name, TravelCost.distanceInKm / Car.kmPerLitre AS "Cost in Litres"
FROM 
    Employee, Car, TravelCost
WHERE 
    Employee.id = TravelCost.employeeID
    AND Car.regNo = TravelCost.carRegNo
```

It's at this point I get a bit stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, standard, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

You are missing a `GROUP BY` and a `HAVING`:

```
SELECT e.name, SUM(tc.distanceInKm / c.kmPerLitre) AS "Cost in Litres"
FROM Employee e JOIN
     TravelCost tc 
     ON e.id = tc.employeeID JOIN
     Car c
     ON c.regNo = tc.carRegNo
GROUP BY e.name
HAVING SUM(tc.distanceInKm) > 100;
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly, I'd tried something very similar previously but had missed off the SUM in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Better perfomant query could be if we joined with grouped data of criteria using CTE or apply

Answer (score 1):

Use Group By and Having Clause

```
SELECT NAME,
       Sum(TravelCost.distanceInKm/ Car.kmPerLitre) AS "Cost in Litres"
FROM   Employee
       INNER JOIN TravelCost
               ON Employee.id = TravelCost.employeeID
       INNER JOIN Car
               ON Car.regNo = TravelCost.carRegNo
GROUP  BY NAME
HAVING Sum(distanceInKm) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to JOIN all the tables and find sum of litres like this:

```
select
    e.*,
    sum(distanceInKm/c.kmPerLitre) litres
from employee e
inner join travelcost t
on e.id = t.employeeId
inner join car c
on t.carRegNo = c.regNo
group by e.id, e.name
having sum(t.distanceInKm) > 100;
```

Also, you need to group by id instead of just names as the other answers suggest. There can be multiple employees with same name.

Also, use explicit JOIN syntax instead of older comma based syntax. It's modern and clearer.

Answer (score -2):

```
-- **How fool am I! How arrogant am I! I just thought `sum(tc.distanceInKm/c.kmPerLitre)` 
-- may have a problem, since a employee may have multiple cars,and car's kmPerLitre is differenct. 
-- However there is no problem, it's simple and right! 
-- The following is what I wrote, what a bloated statement it is! **

-- calcute the total number of litres used by the employee on all journeys
select  e.name, sum(Cost_in_Litres) as "Cost in Litres"
from (
    select t.employeeID
        -- calcute the litres used by the employee on all journeys group by carRegNo
        , sum(t.distanceInKm)/avg(c.kmPerLitre) as Cost_in_Litres
    from TravelCost t
    inner join Car c
        on c.regNo = t.carRegNo
    where t.employeeID in 
    ( -- find the employees who has a total distance from all journeys of more than 100
    select employeeID 
        from TravelCost
        group by employeeID 
        having sum(distanceInKm)> 100
    )
    group by t.carRegNo, t.employeeID
) a
inner join Employee e
    on e.id = a.employeeID
group by e.id,e.name;
```